# calling variables from other functions by using self._variable, and why it seems to work and not work by random (there must be a reason)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this snippet of code I'm trying to understand piece by piece.

Inside one class (called: 'Window') there's a whole lot of functions that reference each other by the method of ***self._variable***

For example this ***loadFiles(self)*** function provides the ***self._filenames*** (second to last line):

```
def loadFiles(self):
    if self.sourceDirectory.text():
        initDir = self.sourceDirectory.text()
    else:
        initDir = str(Path.home())
    files, filter = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(
        self, "Choose Files to Rename", initDir, filter=FILTERS
    )
    if len(files) > 0:
        sourceDirectory = str(Path(files[0]).parent)
        self.sourceDirectory.setText(sourceDirectory)
        for file in files:
            self._files.append(Path(file))
        self._filesCount = len(self._files)
        self._filenames = files
        self.current_index = 0
```

And this function below can easily read that variable, it's in the topmost row (the **self._current_index** comes elsewhere from the code). But I just don't understand, why the self._variables (last line) ***that I make*** don't work? When I try to call my variable into another function with line ***extension = self._test*** I get this *AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute '_test'*:

```
def renameFiles(self):
    filename = self._filenames[self._current_index]
    newFilename = self.createNewFilename()
    self.currentFileName.setText(newFilename)
    dirname = os.path.dirname(filename)
    fullPath = os.path.join(dirname, newFilename)
    os.replace(filename,fullPath)
    self._filenames[self._current_index] = fullPath
    self.current_index = self._current_index
    self._test = fullPath
```

I hope you understand what I'm after here. I can provide more info if needed.

Here's the whole code in cleaned, working condition, except it needs the other .py files to function fully: https://gist.github.com/manujarvinen/fc727cd1d12b6ef2c708a40c32cc3ce1

If you want to check out all the files of this project, get them here (PyQt5 and Python3): https://files.manujarvinen.com/MyMaterial_Rename_Tool_v1.1.zip

Comment: I don't see any reason a single `_` prefix `self._foo` should work differently than `self.foo`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @ggorlen Will do, just a sec .... ->  (and yes, the underscore variable is just a convention, I've heard, the point is why the self. variables that I make can't be called)

Comment: it seems to me that You call the other method before calling this one meaning that the variable does not YET exist, You can also create this variable in the constructor method (`__init__`) and say set it to `None` so that it has some kind of a default value and such an error is avoided

Comment: @Matiiss Thank you! I shall try this immediately. Then I get back to making that minimal reproducible example

Comment: @Matiiss Hmmmm, now I get TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Comment: @ManuJärvinen well yes, depending on how You use that variable may cause other issues, in such cases I would usually put a check in place to check if the value is what I want it to be so for example `if value is None` or `if not value:` then `return` or sth similar, the thing is that You first have to call the `renameFiles()` method so that `self._test` gets set. also if You are working with strings as in this case setting `self._test = ''` should also work fine

Comment: @Matiiss Thanks! I'll fiddle a bit, let's see

Comment: @Matiiss Hmm, this sort of worked, no errors anymore. But now the self._extension is just an empty variable with ''  -  and that variable is depended on the variables inside the loadFiles function, and loadFiles function gets called when I open the FileDialog  :/ this is getting tricky. I can't have the FileDialog to open as soon as I start up the main Python file (if I put it under __init__), it has to be opened on a button press. Dang it... I'm in deep swamp right now.... dunno what to do - AH, maybe I create my variables under the loadFiles function, I'll try...

Comment: YES! WORKED, wohoo! Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the instance variables with a sentinel value inside the constructor, then inside your methods check them and make the program react accordingly, e.g.:

```
if self._test is None:
    do_something
else:
    do_else
```

If you don't want your `__init__` to be a whole aggregation of temporary variables initialisations, you can check their existence calling hasattr(), e.g.:

```
if not hasattr(self, "_test"):
    do_something
else:
    do_else
```